# meteorjs subscribe usage when collection is huge

Tags: javascript, mongodb, collections, meteor

I don't know the best way to handle huge mongo databases with meteorjs.

In my example I have a database collection with addresses in it with the geo location. (the whole code snippets are just examples)

Example:

```
{
   address : 'Some Street',
   geoData : [lat, long]
}
```

Now I have a form where the user can enter an address to get the geo-data. Very simple. But the problem is, that the collection with the geo data has millions of documents in it.

In Meteor you have to publish a collection on Server side and to subscribe on Client and Server side. So my code is like this:

```
// Client / Server

Geodata = new Meteor.collection('geodata');

// Server side
Meteor.publish('geodata', function(){
  return Geodata.find();
});

// Client / Server
Meteor.subscribe('geodata');
```

Now a person has filled the form - after this I get the data. After this I search for the right document to return. My method is this:

```
// Server / Client
Meteor.methods({
 getGeoData : function (address) {
    return Geodata.find({address : address});
 }
});
```

The result is the right one. And this is still working. But my question is now:

Which is the best way to handle this example with a huge database like in my example ? The problem is that Meteor saves the whole collection in the users cache when I subscribed it. Is there a way to subscribe to just the results I need and when the user reused the form then I can overwrite the subscribe? Or is there another good way to save the performance with huge databases and the way I use it in my example?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it doesn't make sense to ship your entire collection to the client, you can use methods to retrieve data from the server.

In your case, you can call the `getGeoData` function when the form is filled out and then display the results after the method returns. Try taking the following steps:

1. Clearly divide your client and server code into their respective `client` and `server` directories if you haven't already.
2. Remove the `geodata` subscription on the server (only clients can activate subscriptions).
3. Remove the `geodata` publication on the server (assuming this isn't needed anymore).
4. Define the `getGeoData` method only on the server. It should return an object, not a cursor so use `findOne` instead of `find`.
5. In your form's `submit` event, do something like:

```js
Meteor.call('getGeoData', address, function(err, geoData){Session.set('geoDataResult', geoData)});
```

You can then display the `geoDataResult` data in your template.

Comment: to point 2: This was an error in my example. in my currently script i just have it on client side. I will check the rest and comment your idea after this! Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: I liked this approach, since you won't need reactivity (the address geocode won't be changing constantly) the Meteor.method is the best from a performance perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```
// client
Deps.autorun(function () {
  // will re subscribe every the 'center' session changes
  Meteor.subscribe("locations", Session.get('center'));
});

// server
Meteor.publish('locations', function (centerPoint) {
  // sanitize the input
  check(centerPoint, { lat: Number, lng: Number });
  // return a limited number of documents, relevant to our app
  return Locations.find({ $near: centerPoint, $maxDistance: 500 }, { limit: 50 });
});
```

Your clients would ask only for some subset of the data at the time. i.e. you don't need the entire collection most of the time, usually you need some specific subset. And you can ask server to keep you up to date only to that particular subset. Bare in mind that more different "publish requests" your clients make, more work there is for your server to do, but that's how it is usually done (here is the simplified version).

Notice how we subscribe in a `Deps.autorun` block which will resubscribe depending on the `center` Session variable (which is reactive). So your client can just check out a different subset of data by changing this variable.